# Connect to H2 database using Datagrip client

Tags: h2, datagrip

Connecting to local h2 db from **Datagrip** Client is failing with the below error

> A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working
>   directory is not allowed in the database URL
>   "jdbc:h2:file:localhost:8082/test". Use an absolute path, ~/name,
>   ./name, or the baseDir setting instead.

Comment: As the error message states, use the absolute path.  localhost:8082 seems like you are trying to access the DB using web server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where are the Database Files Stored?** section in http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html helped me to configure and connect.

DB URL Ex: `jdbc:h2:file:C:/db-workspace/h2/data/test`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change data source *Connection type* to *Embedded* and specify path to your database file.

[image: H2 embedded db]

For additional options read [H2 database URL overview](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url)